# Calling a name variable in a message.py

Tags: python-3.x

First off I am extremely new in self-taught Python. I picked up a crash course book, and I am trying to get type of code to work. The error I get is "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable".

I've tried to add ' ' around name, calling it as str(name()), and a couple off the wall things. If someone could explain what the error actually means, and how I'm suppose to use it? I would really appreciate it,

```
#I can't get this program to work for me

name = "Billy"
message = "Hello, " + name() + "!"
print(message)
```

Comment: what do you expect `name()` to do? :)

Comment: name is not a function, so use it as variable message = "Hello, " + name + "!"

Comment: I'm really embarassed that I didn't need to have the ( )! Also, would someone be able to explain what I would actually use the ( ) for? Sorry if this is a terrible question.

Comment: The () would be for a function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> name = "Billy"

is a string object, not a function.
A function is something like the following

```
def sayHello(name):
    print("Hello "+name+" !")
```

A function is where () is valid. To call the function above, my code would be

```
name = "Tom"
sayHello(name)
```

That gives us the following output

> "Hello Tom !"

To print "Hello Billy !", your code should be `print("Hello " + name + " !")` instead.

You cannot do `str(name())`. It is only valid if you define a function called `name` that returns a value, which you want to cast it into a string. 
This is because `name()` calls a function called `name`. Its return value will then be the parameter given to `str(value_returned_by_function_name)` to be converted into a string object.
In your case, `name` is a string object. So `str(name())` is invalid.